# Use props from component in another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

As you might understand, I'm pretty new to React. I tried to search StackOverflow and google this, but I cannot find anything that answers this question.

I'm creating this travel review page. I save a form to a Firebase database and I display it using a component. However, I want to display, say, only the name of a country, but I cannot manage to do that. I'm pretty sure that I must pass it as a prop but I cannot figure out how to do that, exactly.

What I want is to, use this component and decide in the component what to view.

If I'd use this component in some other .js-file, I'd like to do something like this:
 and display only the data that lies withing the field countryName.I'm going to use the country names as a list, that's why I want to single out just the names.

I've played around using props but I cannot get my head around it. Perhaps someone could help out?

Thanks.

This is the function which I use as a component:

```
const CountryList = () => {
    const countries = useCountries()
    return (
        <div className="countries">      
                {countries.map((country) =>
                    <div key={country.id}>
                        <div className="time-entry">
                            Name of review: {country.revName} <br/>
                             Name of Country: {country.countryName}<br/>
                            Destination 1: {country.dest1}<br/>
                            Destination 2: {country.dest2}<br/>
                            Destination 3: {country.dest3}<br/>
                            Beer price: {country.beerPrice}<br/>
                            Food price: {country.foodPrice}<br/>
                            Hostel price: {country.hostelPrice}<br/>
                            Review: {country.review}<br />
                            <img src={country.url} alt="no-img" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to edit the code above to conditionally render *only* a country name in the returned mapped JSX? or something else? It's a little unclear what you are asking for or what your expected result should be.

Comment: Yes. Exactly that. I'll go ahead and edit the post.

Comment: Sorry, I think that I read your comment a bit too fast. What I want is to, use this component and decide in the component what to view.

If I'd use this component in some other .js-file, I'd like to do something like this:
<CountryList data={country.countryName}/> and display only the data that lies withing the field countryName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super simple way could be to pass an array of "fields" you want to display as a prop, and conditionally render UI. If the `displayFields` array includes the name of the country property then render that "field".

Example:

```
const CountryList = ({ displayFields = [] }) => {
  const countries = useCountries();
  return (
    <div className="countries">
      {countries.map(country => (
        <div key={country.id}>
          <div className="time-entry">
            {displayFields.includes("revName") && (
              <div>Name of review: {country.revName}</div>
            )}
            {displayFields.includes("countryName") && (
              <div>Name of Country: {country.countryName}</div>
            )}
            {displayFields.includes("dest1") && (
              <div>Destination 1: {country.dest1}</div>
            )}
            {displayFields.includes("dest2") && (
              <div>Destination 1: {country.dest2}</div>
            )}
            {displayFields.includes("dest3") && (
              <div>Destination 1: {country.dest3}</div>
            )}
            {displayFields.includes("beerPrice") && (
              <div>Beer price: {country.beerPrice}</div>
            )}
            {displayFields.includes("foodPrice") && (
              <div>Food price: {country.foodPrice}</div>
            )}
            {displayFields.includes("hostelPrice") && (
              <div>Hostel price: {country.hostelPrice}</div>
            )}
            {displayFields.includes("review") && <div>Review: {country.review}</div>}
            {displayFields.includes("imgUrl") && <img src={country.url} alt="no-img" />}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Usage:

```
<CountryList displayFields={["countryName", "beerPrice"]} />
```

Comment: Simple, but *very* repetitive. Not as DRY as it could/should be. **But** getting logic to work is the first step, right? :D